# JavaScript - Moving decimal place to the right

Tags: javascript, decimal

I'm trying to get the decimal place to move to the right and give me at least a 2 digit whole number. I've got the places after the decimal figured out, but not before the decimal.

The input value is divided by 36 and it's supposed to result in a percentage.

There's a fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/WuMpz/11/)**...

```
$(function() {
    var output_element = $('#creditRemaining');

    $('#creditRemaining').keyup(function() {  
        updateTotal();
    });


    var updateTotal = function () {
      var input1 = parseInt($('#creditRemaining').val() || 0);
      $('#total').text((input1 / 36).toFixed(2) + "% Prorated");
    };

 });
```

**Thoughts?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiply it by 100 and then use `.toFixed(2)`

Then this line looks like this:

```
$('#total').text(((input1 / 36)*100).toFixed(2) + "% Prorated");
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting better at this stuff. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfrogs/WuMpz/13/)

Comment: I know. I still have to wait 7 minutes.

Comment: Done. Keep on coding my friend!